# Display progress of . video playing using Iframe youtube player api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, youtube-iframe-api

I've embedded youtube video using their ipframe API. I am able to load a video and play. However, I want to show the current time of the video on the UI. It never refreshes until there is UI event, like I click on a button. I am using Angular 8. here is my template code:

```
...
<button class="btn btn-dark mb-5" (click)="onMute()">Mute</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark mb-5" (click)="onUnmute()">Unmute</button>
</div>
<p>Progress: {{videoProg}}</p>

<!-- YT Player will embed IP frame below.-->
<div class="mt-1" id="player"></div>
```

Here is my component code:

```
  this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => {
  this.videoProg = this.cleanTime()
  console.log("check progress fired. ", this.videoProg);
});
```

Here is how the UI looks:
[image: Progress vlue stays empty until some UI event like button click happens.]

Comment: Can you show more code? What kind of observable is 'source'. Where does it get the events from

Comment: Source is just a plain Observable from rxjs.

const source: Observable<number> = interval(10000);

Comment: Are you using `OnPush`?

Comment: no. What is that? I am a beginner in Javascript

Comment: Can you show more code? Or create a stackblitz showing your issue. Also show your cleanTime() method

Comment: Here is the link. Thank you!  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7j9qm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like I expected :) your events come from a non so called monkey patched event system within the youtube library. Any events fired from here are not patched by the zone.js and therefore will run outside of the angular NgZone.

To fix this, you need to inject the `NgZone` and use the `ngZone.run()` to get your code back into the change detection:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

events: {
  'onStateChange': (event) => this.ngZone.run(() => this.onPlayerStateChange(event)),
  'onError': (event) => this.ngZone.run(() => this.onPlayerError(event)),
  'onReady': (event) => this.ngZone.run(() => this.onPlayerReady(event))
}
```

[working stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9fw3k1?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Just letting you know that you are a hero :) I knew that this was the problem but I had no idea how to solve it. Thanks!